# Rspec mocks, can 'expect' also stub a method as a side effect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I'm trying to make sense of the tests in an inherited app, and I need some help.

There are lots of spec groups like this one (view spec):

```
let(:job_post) { FactoryGirl.create(:job_post) }

# ...

before do
  expect(view).to receive(:job_post).at_least(:once).and_return(job_post)
end

it "should render without error" do
  render
end
```

... with `job_post` being an helper method defined on the controller. (yes, they could have used @instance variables, and I'm in the process of refactoring it).

Now, in my opinion using an `expect` inside a `before` block is wrong. Let's forget about that for a second.

Normally the test above is green.
However, if I **remove** the `expect` line, the test fails. It appears that in this case `expect` is stubbing the method on the view. In fact, replacing `expect` with `allow` seems to have exactly the same effect.

I think that what's going on is that normally – when run with a server – the view will call `job_posts` and the message will *land* on the helper method on the controller, which is the expected behaviour.

Here, however, `expect` is setting an expectation and, at the same time, stubbing a method on the `view` with a fixed return value. Since the view template **will** call that method, the test passes.

About that unexpected "stub" side effect of `expect`, I've found this in the [rspec-mocks readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#test-specific-extension):

> (...) We can also set a message expectation so that the example fails if find is not called:
>
> ```
> person = double("person")
> expect(Person).to receive(:find) { person }
> ```
>
> RSpec **replaces the method we're stubbing or mocking with its own test-double-like method**. At the end of the example, RSpec verifies any message expectations, and then restores the original methods.

Does anyone have any experience with this specific use of the method?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, that's what `expect().to receive()` does! This is the (not so) new [expectation syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) of `rspec`, which replaces the `should_receive` API

```
expect(view).to receive(:job_post).at_least(:once).and_return(job_post)
```

is equivalent to

```
view.should_receive(:job_post).at_least(:once).and_return(job_post)
```

and this API sets the expectation *and* the return value. This is the default behavior. To actually *call* the original method as well, you need to explicitly say so:

```
view.should_receive(:job_post).at_least(:once).and_call_original
```

On to some other issues:

> (yes, they could have used @instance variables, and I'm in the process of refactoring it).

`let` API is very ubiquitous in rspec testing, and may be better than @instance variables in many cases (for example - it is lazy, so it runs only if needed, and it is memoized, so it runs at most once).

> In fact, replacing `expect` with `allow` seems to have exactly the same effect.

The `allow` syntax replaces the `stub` method in the old rspec syntax, so yes, it has the same effect, but the difference is, that it won't fail the test if the stubbed method is *not* called.

---

As the OP requested - some explanations about [`should_receive`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/message-expectations) - unit tests are expected to run *in isolation*. This means that everything which is not *directly* part of your test, should not be tested. This means that HTTP calls, IO reads, external services, other modules, etc. are not part of the test, and for the purpose *of* the test, you should *assume* that they work correctly.

What you *should* include in your tests is that those HTTP calls, IO reads, and external services *are* called correctly. To do that, you set **message expectations** - you *expect* the tested method to *call* a certain method (whose actual functionality is out of the scope of the test). So you *expect* the service *to receive* a method call, with the correct arguments, one or more times (you can explicitly expect how many times it should be called), and, in exchange for it actually being called, you stub it, and according to the test, set its return value.

**Sources:**

- [Message expectation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/message-expectations)
- [RSpec's New Expectation Syntax](http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/)

Comment: thanks. When I mentioned the instance variables I was actually talking about the controllers, not the tests. Who worked on the project before me had an aversion to views using controllers' @instance variables, and has created accessors for all of them.

Comment: Also, great answer... but could you please expand on `should_receive`? I've always used `stub` and `allow`, and I always assumed that `expect(obj).to receive` was setting an expectation __only__.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I'm aware of the importance of mocks and stubs in unit tests. However, I've always explicitly used `stub/allow` to stub a method, and then `shout_receive/expect().to receive` to test the message. I was just surprised that `expect` handles it automatically... and I find it a bit confusing, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec is a meta-gem, which depends on the rspec-core, rspec-expectations and rspec-mocks gems. 
Rspec-mocks is a test-double framework for rspec with support for method stubs, fakes, and message expectations on generated test-doubles and real objects alike.

```
allow().to receive
```

is the use of 'Method Stubs', however

```
expect().to receive
```

is the use of 'Message Expectations'

You can refer to the [Doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames) for more details

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to stub as a side affect, you can always call the original.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method

For example I once wanted to spy on a method, but also call the function else it has other side affects. That really helped.

`https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method`